# using flex box to move numbers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.header  {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
  }

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}
.left-links{display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flex Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="left-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
      <div class="right-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i'm trying to make the left-links to move to the left side of the container and the right-links to move to the right side of the container but every time i type justify-content:flex-start for left side and flex-end for right side they wont move to the edges of their respective side.

Answer (score 1):

Try `justify-content: space-between` on the header:
(I also removed unnecessary flex's and the `ul` default padding)

```css
.header  {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 50px;
  align-items: center; /* added for horizontal alignment */
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
  }

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flex Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="left-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
      <div class="right-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also use `justify-content: space-evenly` instead for centering the `ul` in the `header` segment:

```css
.header  {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 50px;
  align-items: center; /* added for horizontal alignment */
}

.logo {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato;
  background: white;
  padding: 4px 32px;
  }

ul {
  /* this removes the dots on the list items*/
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  /* this removes the line under the links */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flex Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="left-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ONE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TWO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">THREE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
      <div class="right-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FIVE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SIX</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```